# Why using filter() gives what I want, but with get() raises an error

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset, attributeerror

I created cusom QuerySet and Manager to serialize my data.

```
class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        return serialize("json", self)

class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Update(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = UpdateManager()
```

Then, when I'am trying to get this data, it worked with this:

```
json_data = Update.objects.filter(id=1).serialize()
```

but raises AttributeError ('Update' object has no attribute 'serialize') with this:

```
json_data = Update.objects.get(id=1).serialize()
```

Comment: Because `.filter` returns a `queryset` while `get` returns the `object` ?

Comment: `.serialize` is a function on an `UpdateQuerySet` object, `.filter()` returns such `QuerySet`, whereas `.get()` is just a simple object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Update.objects.filter(id=1)` returns an `UpdateQueryset`, and that `QuerySet` offers a `.serialize(…)` method. The `.get(id=1)` function will return an `Update` model *object*, so not a `QuerySet`, and a model by default does *not* offer a `.serialize(…)` method.

You can however implement this yourself, and even generalize the `QuerySet` to work with all sorts of models, like:

```
class SerializableQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        return serialize('json', self)

class SerializableManager(models.Manager):
    _queryset_class = SerializableQuerySet

    def serialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().serialize(*args, **kwargs)

class SerializableModel(models.Model):
    objects = SerializableManager()
    
    def serialize(self):
        return serialize('json', [self])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Update(SerializableModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So now all models that inherit from `SerializableModel`, like `Update` for example now will use a `SerializableManager`, and furthermore will inherit a `.serialize()` method, such that you can also work with `Update.objects.get(pk=1).serialize()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You also want to add `serialize` to the `UpdateManager`

```
class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def serialize(self):
        return self.get_queryset().serialize()
```